# Better way to phrase this question

Tags: support, asking-questions

Can someone suggest a better way to phrase this so the site does not reject it:

Why don't we kiss the tzitzit during the vehaya section of shma of maariv?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, it's important to explain the premise of your question.

Here your premise is that we should kiss our titzis during Maariv.
I suggest you explain more about why you think that we should. In this case, the answer would be that we do it during Shacharis, so add that information (and any other information you think would be useful) into your question.

I believe that the StackExchange engine will reject any question whose body contains almost nothing besides a repetition of the question title.